# Height tag is not working since Chrome version 50.xx

Tags: css, google-chrome, screen-orientation

Since received a new Google Chrome (desktop) upgrade, pages do not listen the "height: 100%;" tag used in CSS files. Works fine with IE. All of our div panels are invisible. The project has quite a lot of pages with this kind of usage.

Sample usage as following;

```
div.ElementToScroll {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 100%;
    ...
```

Tried `"height:100vh"` instead and turned out they are not working in the same way and pages had different behaviors in different screen resolution.

Could somebody propose a solution? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you share some code or fiddle to rectify the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wrong misleading question. It turned out, method `jQuery.browser.safari` is returning true for Chrome. Some of the browser based scripts were skipped then and the page behaviour changed.

Instead used;

```
var is_safari = /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);
```

Answer (score 1):

It doens't occurs always. In some divs it works correctly. In others the div is invisible. By now, I have solved this problem removing the style 'height:100%' and leaving 'overflow:auto' in the affected div.